# Property assignment on a graph vertex using PropertyValue does not work inside a function

Tags: graphs-and-networks, function-construction

I created this function:

```
AddStone[board_Graph, v_, s : white | black | empty] := 
   PropertyValue[{board, v}, VertexState] = s
```

This function should change the VertexState property of vertex `v` in graph `board` to one of `white`, `black`, or `empty`.  That's simple enough, right? Then I created a graph:

```
board = GridGraph[{5, 5}];
```

But then if I execute:

```
AddStone[board, 8, white]
```

I get an error:

> "Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object PropertyValue[{ ... ,8},VertexState]=white."

where the "..." stands for an image of the graph `board`, which I obviously need not draw here.

In the Documentation for `PropertyValue` it is stated that one can set properties this way. In fact, the code

```
PropertyValue[{board, 4}, VertexState] = white
```

does work without issuing any messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, a function evaluates it's arguments before plugging them into the function definition, so in effect `AddStone` is trying to set the property of the value of `board` instead of `board` itself. To get around this you could set the attribute `HoldFirst` which tells a function to substitute the unevaluated form of the first argument into the right-hand side. So for example

```
Clear[AddStone];
SetAttributes[AddStone, HoldFirst];
AddStone[board_ /; Head[board] === Graph, v_, s : (white | black | empty)] :=   
   (PropertyValue[{board, v}, VertexState] = s)

board = GridGraph[{5, 5}];

AddStone[board, 8, white]

PropertyValue[{board, 8}, VertexState]
```

Comment: An almost identical answer so I deleted mine. Just 1 minute difference...

Comment: It works. But then I tried using `board_Graph` instead of `board_ /; Head[board] === Graph` and it didn't work. Why?

Comment: @becko Because with HoldFirst you're now not sending a Graph but a symbol *referring* to a Graph, which isn't the same.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Got it.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I just realized I have one more question. What does a `Graph` object evaluate to? I thought they were atomic. Why do I have to put a `HoldFirst`? When I create a function that takes as argument an `Integer`, I'll just use `f[x_Integer]`, and I don't have to put a `HoldFirst`. So, if `Graph` is atomic, shouldn't it behave in the same way?

Comment: @becko you could look at it the following way: does this definition make sense to you? `f[x_Integer,c_Integer]:=x=c` and yes, a Graph seems to be atomic.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Ok. Now I *almost* got it. Except for the fact that now I don't understand how `PropertyValue` works, since it doesn't have a `HoldFirst` attribute: `Attributes[PropertyValue]` returns `{Protected}`. To me it looks contrary to the behavior that you explain, but I guess I'm missing something ... ??

Comment: @becko But `Set` does have the attribute `HoldFirst`, so in `PropertyValue[....] = new`, the whole left-hand side is held, including the `Graph` object.

Comment: @Heike Eureka!!