# Is it possible to use PropertyValue to modify properties of Graph objects in a list?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, function-construction

This post can be seen as a follow up to [Property assignment on a graph vertex using PropertyValue does not work inside a function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5826/534).

I have defined a function:

```
Clear[AddStone];
SetAttributes[AddStone, HoldFirst];
AddStone[board_, v_, s : (white | black | empty)] := (PropertyValue[{board, v}, VertexState] = s)
```

This function should change the VertexState property of vertex `v` in a graph `board` to one of `white`, `black`, or `empty`. It works as expected (credits to @Heike), as the execution of:

```
 board = GridGraph[{5, 5}];

 AddStone[board, 8, white]

 PropertyValue[{board, 8}, VertexState]
```

demonstrates.

But now suppose that I need to change the property `VertexState` of vertices of Graphs in a list. For example:

```
 list = {CycleGraph[5], KaryTree[8]}
```

The following code doesn't work as expected:

```
 AddStone[list[[1]], 3, white]
```

It returns the error:

> Set::setraw: "Cannot assign to raw object PropertyValue[{list[[1]],3},VertexState]=white."

From the discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5826/534), I have an idea of why this happens (though a clear explanation would be appreciated). So I need an alternative way to change the properties of the graphs in a list, when all I have is the list (instead of references to the graphs themselves). I know I could apply `SetProperty` to the list and obtain a new list of graphs with the updated properties, but `SetProperty` is slower than `PropertyValue` because it creates a new copy of the graph with the property changed instead of modifying the original graph.

Summing up, here is my **question**: Is there a way to use `PropertyValue` to modify the properties of graphs in a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using `SetProperty` instead of `PropertyValue`:

```
SetAttributes[AddStone2, HoldFirst];
AddStone2[board_, v_, s : (white | black | empty)] :=
   board = SetProperty[{board, v}, VertexState -> s]

list = {CycleGraph[5], KaryTree[8]};
AddStone2[list[[1]], 1, black];

PropertyValue[{list[[1]], 1}, VertexState]

(* out: black *)
```

Comment: As I said in the question, the problem with `SetProperty` is that it is slower than `PropertyValue`. I'm working with a large list of huge graphs, and the difference is felt.

Comment: This seems to be the better approach

Comment: @becko: have you made some experiments? Just being curious, I have myself not used `Graph` for anything serious, but would be interested to learn more about them, they look interesting after all...

Comment: @AlbertRetey I have only been using `Graph` for a couple of weeks. They are pretty handy, but I think it still needs some polishing. On the particular issue in this question, I ended up doing something entirely different (see next comment). My decision to mark this as the answer is based on the argument I gave in the comments (that `SetProperty` does only one copy). But I haven't run any experiments that demonstrate that this is, in fact, the best approach.

Comment: @AlbertRetey What I am doing is that I am working on the lists of edges directly. Properties are added and modified as wrappers. Only when I am finished and I want to see the result I add the `Graph` wrapper to the list of edges. So far it has been faster to work like this.

Comment: @AlbertRetey If you do some runs that show that your approach is faster, I'll be happy to mark your answer. If the experiments show that Heike's is faster, you should post them anyway. It'll be useful information.

Comment: @becko: don't be worried about marking my answer, it wasn't my intention to make you change that (I even suggested to use Heikes answer). I was suggesting that **you** do some experiments because I don't even have a feeling what a relevant test case would be and results from what I tried with simple things were not showing a clear trend. It's interesting to see that your final solution does circumvent the internals completely. Should probably be seen as a hint to the developers :-)

Answer (score 4):

Honestly it's not quite clear to me to which extent `Graph` is to be seen as an internal *atomic* datatype or rather just an expression with head `Graph`. `AtomicQ` returns `True` which indicates the former, but other than that it behaves a lot like the latter. If it really is an internal datatype, my solution might be inefficient and rather a workaround, but it does the job: Just add the following pattern to your `AddStone` definitions:

```
AddStone[list_[[idx__]], v_, s : (white | black | empty)] := 
 Module[{g = list[[idx]]},
  AddStone[g, v, s];
  list[[idx]] = g;
  ]
```

And you can use something like:

```
AddStone[listofgraphs[[1]], 3, white]
```

but also:

```
AddStone[arrayofgraphs[[1,2]], 3, white]
```

I would consider it at least an oversight that `PropertyValue[{g[[1]],1},prop]=val;` doesn't work out of the box, especially since `PropertyValue[{g[[1]],1},prop]` works as expected.  I think this could and should be added to `PropertyValue`.

**Edit:** I think Heikes answer is the way to go. I'll leave this here since it might be instructive for similar cases where no better alternative is available.

**Edit:** Some notes about memory efficiency which my remark about whether `Graph` is really an internal datatype is all about: If `Graph` is just a wrapper for a normal expression I'd expect exactly one "real" copy to be made, whichever approach you take. The second copy will actually not cause any extra memory to be used due to the "copy on write" that Mathematica uses for general expressions, AFAIK. If it is an internal datatype it might be possible to change it in place, and that would of course be lost with my above way of doing things. But then, I think you are out of luck if only `PropertyValue` applies changes in place but `SetProperty` doesn't. You should also note that if `Graph` is an internal datatype, `SetProperty` could in principle make changes in place even without having an `Hold` attribute. From some superficial tests I think that `Graph` does behave a lot like a normal expression, though. Since it is quite difficult to make precise forecasts how much extra memory each approach will need and how fast they'd be I'd just try that out. My own tests look like what I did suggest could be worth a try, despite the fact that an extra copy is made.

Comment: For some reason I can't get this to work.

Comment: Strange, it worked for me. I probably should make clear that you will need your definitions and additionally the one I gave. If that's not the problem, can you show what exactly you are trying?

Comment: It works now. I don't know what went wrong before. However, this approach still copies the graph to change the property, (when you do `g = list[[idx]]`, the graph is *copied* to `g`, and then there is another copy in `list[[idx]] = g`). So as you say, it is probably better to use `SetProperty` (as Heike suggests), which involves only *one* copy.

Comment: I would very much like to see an approach that doesn't need to copy the `Graph`. I think that `PropertyValue`, as it stands now, is severely limited if it can't be used as I intend it.